# I want to return a VALUE for given KEY for map<> in c++. What to return in case KEY is not present in map<>?

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, return-value

I wrote class with template. class has map as member and some getxxx() / setxxx() member functions.

```
template<typename T1,typename T2>
class C1{
    map<T1,T2> M;
public:
    map<T1,T2> getM();
    T2 getMvalue(T1 Key);
    void setM(T1 key,T2 Value);
};
```

here I want to implement getMvalue(), where it recieves key as argument and returns the corresponding "value" if "key" is available in mapM.

It look something like...

```
template<typename TKey,typename TValue>
T2 C1<T1,T2>::getMvalue(T1 Key){
    if(M.count(Key)>0)
        return M[Key];
    else
        return(???);
};
```

Here I need to use something in place of ???. keeping in mind that return type of function is T2, which can be anything depending on user decision.
How can i replace "???" and with what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would encourage you to use the `TryGet` pattern

```
template<typename TKey,typename TValue>
bool C1<T1,T2>::tryGetMvalue(T1 key, T2& value){
    if(M.count(key)>0) {
        value = objProperties[key];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: This is what I was in the process of suggesting when you beat me to it... +1

Comment: There will be hundreds of key-value pairs in map<>, and there are going to be thousands of such class objects.

So while searching for a KEY in a map<> of each object is going to have higher time complexity.

In this situation how much it'll be better to use such technique (using tryGet) which will demand 'twice' searching in case KEY is present.

Comment: @NDThokare: You can use `find()` rather than your `count()` and `[]` combination; then there will only be one search.

Comment: @paul23 That would construct a value even when there's nothing to return. An optional type (e.g. `boost::optional`) holds as much information as `std::pair<bool, T>` but doesn't have that drawback however.

Answer (score 2):

Your choices are three:

1. `throw` an exception
2. Modify the signature so you can return out-of-band data (this is what [@JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622391/8747))
3. Return in-band data.

If you *must* choose 3, I would return the default value (this is what `std::map::operator[]` does):

```
template<typename TKey,typename TValue>
  T2 C1<T1,T2>::getMvalue(T1 Key){
    if(M.count(Key)>0)
      return M[Key];
    else
      return T2();
  };
```

Beware, design choice #3 leads to bugs. The caller can't distinguish between "nominal value" and "not present".

---

P.s. If you do return the default value, then your code might simplify to:

```
template<typename TKey,typename TValue>
T2 C1<T1,T2>::getMvalue(T1 Key){
  return M[key];
}
```

Comment: In this second case,

operator[]: Returns a reference to the value of the element with key key, Inserts an element with key if it does not yet exist. which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

By using `operator[]`, you've already restricted yourself to only storing default-constructible values; so you could return `TKey()` - unless the user needs to be able tell whether or not it was actually found.

If you don't want that restriction, then you'd have to change it to something like:

```
auto found = map.find(key);
if (found != map.end()) {
    return found->second;
} else {
    return ???;
}
```

Now the simplest ways to indicate failure are to change the return type to a pointer (or perhaps `boost::optional` if you want to return by value), and return null (or `boost::none`); or to return the result through a reference parameter and indicate success with a boolean return value; or to throw an exception.

Comment: Any reason for preferring `boost::optional` over a pointer?  If the function calculates a value, and has to return an rvalue, something like `boost::optional` (but with a better name) is ideal, but when you're guaranteed an lvalue, a pointer seems simpler (to me at least).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Not particularly; I just thought I'd mention it. It would be useful in a similar situation where you need to return a local object, and so can't return a pointer.

Comment: It's definitely getting to be the end of the week.  I just saw `boost::optional` highlighted, and missed the fact that you'd also proposed a pointer.  (I agree that it's worth mentioning.  Although the name hardly fits for this case, and most of us who were around before Boost already had a better named alternative in our toolkit.)

Answer (score 1):

Several possibilities.  The simplest is have the getter return a
pointer, with a null pointer if the key isn't in the map.
Alternatively, you can have it return a Fallible (or Maybe, or
whatever you call it); while a good solution in general, it seems like
overkill here.  Or finally, you can simply throw an exception if the
object isn't present.